# ffmpeg covert yuv to mp4 failed :"Invalid buffer size, packet size"

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv, avi

Hi  I am trying to convert  YUV video to a avi formt with the following command:
"`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 512x512 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i output3.yuv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 output.avi`"

Then I got an error 
`[rawvideo @ 0x1c9e620] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'output3.yuv':
  Duration: 00:00:01.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 79250 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 512x512, 78643 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'output.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x1ca93e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x1ca93e0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.0, 4:2:0 8-bit
Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 512x512, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rawvideo @ 0x1ca7fa0] **Invalid buffer size, packet size 130560 < expected frame_size 393216**
**Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument**
frame=   43 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    8389kB time=00:00:01.72 bitrate=39954.8kbits/s

video:8382kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.078511%`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You omitted the version info, but it looks like you're using FFmpeg 2.8 which is ancient. First step is always to try a recent version. Go to the [FFmpeg download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds if you don't want to compile.

Comment: Thanks.Now I update ffmpeg to the latest version :4.2.1-2~16.04.
The problem  persists.

Comment: I found that he input file is a grayscale video and this doesn't work.

Comment: The error seems to be from the last frame. Does the output look fine? You probably have an incorrect input option value, and use `-video_size`, `-pixel_format`, and `-framerate` input options for the [rawvideo demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) instead of `-s`, `-r`, and `-pix_fmt`. If it is grayscale then use the appropriate pixel format. See `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` for a list.

Comment: Thanks.  The command line seems right because if I give a colorful yuv file as the input then I can get the right output. But if I give a gray-scale yuv file as input the above issue will happen. How can I convert a grey yuv file(only has Y component) to avi?

Comment: If it is a true grayscale input then don't use `-pixel_format yuv420p`: use the appropriate pixel format for the input such as `-pixel_format gray` (that's just an example as I do not know what pixel format your input is).